# Typescript Angular2 error cannot find module angular/x

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

This app uses jspm for javascript module loading, so all of the angular2 typescript definition files are in jspm_modules folder.  I get errors that Typescript cannot find module 'angular/core', 'angular/route', 'angular/http', etc.  I get the error both in VS 2015 editor and when I run my build, which is using gulp-typescript.  I thought maybe it's because I have jspm_packages in my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/jspm_packages",
    "wwwroot/app"
  ]
}
```

But if I remove that line, I get all kinds of duplicate names errors.  I've tried editing my xproj file as suggested in other similar questions, but to no avail.  Any ideas how to fix this problem?

[image]

The source code is available on github.

https://github.com/ryanlangton/angular2-asp5-starter/tree/typescript-errors

Comment: I think an `npm install` in the `package.json` directory  should fix this. TypeScript Compiler will find type definition automatically in your `node_modules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an `npm install` in the `package.json` directory should fix this. TypeScript Compiler will find type definition automatically in your `node_modules`.

The problem is that dependency resolution is two-folded in a JSPM powered Angualr2 apps.

The **compiling phase**, which is `gulp-typescript` in this case, will find Angular2 module accroding to typescript compiler's rule. `tsc` will conventionally follow typing files in `node_modules`. So if you install Angular2 by npm locally, `gulp-typescript` will resolve it correctly.

The **runtime phase** is totally a different story, though. In browser all dependencies are resolved by jspm, which configured by `config.js`. Your typescript is compiled to javascript, so tsc does not interfere here. Systemjs will find `angular2` in `jspm_packages`.

So, it seems your compiling phase dependencies are not installed. Try with `npm install`?

Comment: So sad, jspm is not npm compatible :(. Usually you need install one module twice in both jspm and npm